# How to update a record using nhibernate

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, nhibernate

Hi i am working in MVC3 and for database communication i am using NHIBERNATE

 I am getting a problem in updating a record.

Firstly session.SaveorUpdate does not work
Then i tried the following thing but this also does not work:(

```
  public bool EditParentStudent(ParentStudent parentstudent)
        {
            log.Debug("Start");
            if (parentstudent == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException("parentstudent");
            }
            ISession session = DataAccessLayerHelper.OpenWriterSession();
            ITransaction transaction = session.BeginTransaction();
            bool saved = false;
            try
            {
                session.SaveOrUpdate(parentstudent);
                transaction.Commit();
                saved = true;
            }
            catch (SessionException ex)
            {
                if (transaction != null && transaction.IsActive)
                transaction.Rollback();
                log.Error(ex);
            }
            finally
            {
                if (transaction != null)
                    transaction.Dispose();

                if (session != null && session.IsConnected)
                    session.Close();
            }
            log.Debug("End");

            return saved;
        }
```

Comment: You definitely need to provide more information. What means "does not work"? Exception? What is the error message? Are there no changes in the DB? How do you test it? How do you call this method? What is the expected result? ...? ...?

Answer (score 2):

If your entity is persistent you don't need to update it explicitly.

```
using (var session = sessionFactory.OpenSesion())
using (var tx = session.BeginTransaction())
{
    // perform your insert here
    tx.Commit();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your mapping is ok, if you are using mvc3 then you should put code inside controller, for example

```
public ActionResult Edit(ParentStudent parentstudent)
{
   //open session
   // open transaction
   //found existing data
   var data = session.Query<ParentStudent>().Where(x=>x.Id == parentstudent.Id).FirstOrDefault();
   session.SaveOrUpdate(data);
   transaction.Commit();
  //close transaction
  //close session

 return View();    
}
```

maybe is better to put this code inside try catch block and to catch possible exception, but I was trying to make it simple as possible.

Hope this helps.

Comment: You don't need to SaveOrUpdate entities that are already in the session. Entities that are returned by a query are already in the session, SaveOrUpdate just doesn't do anything.